# Reading data from file and const

Tags: abstraction, io, const

Is it sane to let a read method on a file object to be const? For example

```
size_t read(void* buffer,size_t length) const;
```

The read method does not change the contents of the file, but updates the file pointer which is invisible behind a handle.

Comment: Does it make sense for a file object to be const?

Comment: Yes, since then I can use a temporary file object to load data into memory: Foo bar(File("myfile.txt")); or would it be better to say Foo bar("myfile.txt"); and let the ctor of Foo create the file object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the `read` method does not change the visible state of its object, it *does* change the visible state of the external world (the file handle), and so should not be declared *const*.  Here's why.

Marking a method *const* has two meanings: One to the programmer, and a different one to the compiler.

- To the programmer, *const* says *this method is idempotent*.  I can call it as many times as I want and make no changes in the visible state of this object, its collaborators, or the outside world.  It has no visible side effects.
- To the compiler, *const* means *this method makes no changes to the state of this object*.

To that end, you mark a method as *const* if it meets the programmers's definition of having no visible side effects.  The compiler's definition of *const* is merely a tool that the compiler can use to check your claim that the method is idempotent.

The *mutable* keyword, which you use to tell the compiler that *this* piece of an object's state can be changed and have no visible side effects, is both a tool used to adapt the compiler's understanding of `const` to the programmer's definition, and evidence that the two definitions are not the same.

Comment: So a const declared read method have to make sure that the returend buffer is the same for the next call, either by saving the data read internally (nessecary for a general stream) or saving the file pointer, which has to be restored before the method returns.

Comment: @user877329, Correct.  But what a strange `read` method that would be.

Comment: Yes, but definitely useful if a file header has to be read to see if a specific decoder can be used. Note that different files types have magic numbers of different length.